# In react-admin, how can I prefix a UrlField href?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Let's say I have the following:

`<UrlField source='fbUsername' />`

If the result is fb username `foo`, this links relatively to `/foo`.

(?) How can I prefix this url to:

`https://facebook.com/`

So the result would be:

`https://facebook.com/${fbUsername}`

`https://facebook.com/foo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @françois-zaninotto 's answer, I fixed a syntax error fixed some of the missing useRecordContext() param that made it work:

```
// ###############################################
// FbUrlField.js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useRecordContext } from 'react-admin';

const FbUrlField = ( props ) =>
{
    const { source, target, rel } = props;
    const record = useRecordContext(props);
    const value = record && record[source];

    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Link href={`https://facebook.com/${value}`} target={target} rel={rel}>
            {value}
        </Link>
    );
};

FbUrlField.defaultProps = {
    addLabel: true,
};

export default FbUrlField;


// ###############################################
// SomeList.js
import FbUrlField from './FbUrlField';
[...]
<FbUrlField
    label='FB'
    source='fbUsername'
    target='_blank' // New window
    rel="noopener noreferrer" // For security
/>
```

Comment: To add on to this, I could add a field in `<FbUrlField` called `prefixUrl` and pass it along to the `props` and rename `FbUrlField` to `PrefixedUrlField`, swapping `https://www.facebook.com/` with `${props.prefixUrl}`

Comment: However, there's still 1 issue - if you have row click edit, even though FB opens in a new tab, you still click in their profile. I tried the following that doesn't seem to work: `onClick={ (e) => { e.stopPropagation(); } }`. I need to look into how to implement onClick for this custom UrlField.

Answer (score 3):

`<UrlField>` only accepts a URL value. For your use case, you should write a custom field based on [the `UrlField` source](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/8b09ad9a38947f88674a8a5d84ddadffc7a097ac/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/field/UrlField.tsx). Something like:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useRecordContext } from 'react-admin';

const MyUrlField = ({ source }) => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    const value = record && record[source];

    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Link href={`https://facebook.com/${value}`}>
            {value}
        </Link>
    );
});

MyUrlField.defaultProps = {
    addLabel: true,
};
```

Comment: Thanks bud! However, minus that `)` syntax err at the end of the comment, I have 1:1 your code similar to a vanilla `UrlField` and nothing seems to be showing up: The `UrlField` works, but alas - the `MyUrlField` does not work (nothing shows). Any ideas? Seems to always be returning null @ `if (value == null)` - but again, UrlField has the same source and works (to rule out !source)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to react-admin. I was following the tutorial and came across the idea of doing something like this because the user's website is just bla.com and it doesn't actually work because you get `http://localhost:xxxx/bla.com` as a link. I came up with this method to do it, in typescript. Take it with a grain of salt:

```
/// user-url.field.tsx
import { UrlField, useRecordContext } from 'react-admin';

export const UserURLField = ({source}: {source: string}) => {
  const record = useRecordContext();
  const fakeRecord = {
    [source]: `http://${record[source]}`,
  };
  return (
  <UrlField source={source} record={fakeRecord}></UrlField>
  );
};
```